# Aggregate data from Mongo collection based on dates and other fields, and count

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I keep a collection of events, counting by day. If the event occurs once then it's a 'hit' (billState), this is per location and material class. I am having a hard time getting the data back out that I need, I have tried several examples found here at SO, and many in the Mongo Docs.. usually ending up with only parts of what I need to get out.

Sample of my collection is like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("565ca8678e000995a09d1540"),
    "company" : "someCompany",
    "location" : "123",
    "materialCode" : "MATCODE",
    "materialClass" : "Class",
    "totalCount" : 8,
    "billState" : 1,
    "eventTime" : ISODate("2015-11-30T19:49:59.243Z")
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("565ca9778e000995a09d1541"),
    "company" : "someCompany",
    "location" : "1",
    "materialCode" : "WTHFA",
    "materialClass" : "OtherClass",
    "totalCount" : 16,
    "billState" : 1,
    "eventTime" : ISODate("2015-11-30T19:54:31.695Z")
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("565ca9778e000995a09d1541"),
    "company" : "someCompany",
    "location" : "12345",
    "materialCode" : "WTHFA",
    "materialClass" : "thirdClassOfMat",
    "totalCount" : 16,
    "billState" : 1,
    "eventTime" : ISODate("2015-11-30T19:54:31.695Z")
}
```

I can have several locations & materialClasses and I am only trying to count if "billState" is one (easy because it will not be in the collection otherwise). I need to break it down by Week, location, day, material class.. like so..

```
    week1 mon tue wed thur fri sat sun
          ----------------------------
location 1  -  -   -  Class otherClass  = 2 
location 123-  -   -  Class otherClass  = 2 
    week2 mon tue wed thur fre sat sun
          ----------------------------
locations    material billState Count   = X
                                       -----
                                       month total
```

Currently I can only get to this, based mostly (at this point) on another SO post:

```
{
    "_id" : 12,
    "weeks" : {
        "week" : 48,
        "total" : 6,
        "days" : [ 
            {
                "day" : ISODate("2015-12-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
                "total" : 1
            }, 
            {
                "day" : ISODate("2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
                "total" : 1
            }, 
            {
                "day" : ISODate("2015-11-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
                "total" : 4
            }
        ]
    },
    "monthTotal" : 6
}
```

This is what I have now..

```
myCollection.aggregate([

        // then total per day. Rounding dates
        { "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "$add": [
                    { "$subtract": [
                        { "$subtract": [ "$eventTime", new Date(0) ] },
                        { "$mod": [
                            { "$subtract": [ "$eventTime", new Date(0) ] },
                            1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
                        ]}                        
                    ]},
                    new Date(0)
                ]
            },
            "week": { "$first": { "$week": "$eventTime" } },
            "month": { "$first": { "$month": "$eventTime" } },
            "total": { "$sum": "$billState" }
        }},

        // Then group by week
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$week",
            "month": { "$first": "$month" },
            "days": {
                "$push": {
                    "day": "$_id",
                    "total": "$total"
                }
            },
            "total": { "$sum": "$total" }
        }},

        // Then group by month
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$month",
            "weeks": {
                "$push": {
                    "week": "$_id",
                    "total": "$total",
                    "days": "$days"
                }
            },
            "monthTotal": { "$sum": "$total" }
        }},

        {"$unwind": "$weeks"},

        { $out : "billingTotals" }
    ]);
};
```

I have tried using more $groups, $match and messed with $project but just can't seem to get it broken down far enough by date and including the locations. Really I just need to count the event per day, location, and material class and then sum per week and month. So, on any given day there may be hits for 20 material classes in one location, "X" amount in another location, etc. I will only count a single hit per day, per locaiton, per class.

Edit:
Example of output (I think this is a good idea.., it's been a long day)

```
{
    "month" : 12 {
        "week" : 49 {
            "day" : 3 {
                "location": "123",
                "materials": [
                                {
                                    "class": "materialClass",
                                    "total" : 2
                                },

                                {
                                    "class": "otherMatClass",
                                    "total" : 5
                                }
                             ],
                "location": "1234",
                                "materials": [
                                {
                                    "class": "materialClass",
                                    "total" : 2
                                },

                                {
                                    "class": "otherMatClass",
                                    "total" : 5
                                }
                             ],

            },
            "day" : 4 {
                "location": "123",
                "materials": [
                                {
                                    "class": "materialClass",
                                    "total" : 2
                                },

                                {
                                    "class": "otherMatClass",
                                    "total" : 5
                                }
                             ]
            }

        },
        "week" : 50 {
            "day" : 3 {
                "location": "123",
                "materials": [
                                {
                                    "class": "materialClass",
                                    "total" : 2
                                },

                                {
                                    "class": "otherMatClass",
                                    "total" : 5
                                }
                             ]

            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Please include a sample JSON to demonstrate the result that you're looking for.

Comment: I added an example of how I think it should look.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a while since I have used aggregate method in MongoDB. I put this together with your mock data. Unfortunately did not get exact result; maybe it will still help. Good luck.

```
db.materials.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {billState:{$ne:0}}
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id:{location:"$location",date:{week:{$week:"$eventTime"},month:{$month:"$eventTime"},day:{$dayOfMonth:"$eventTime"},year:{$year:"$eventTime"}}},
        materials:{$addToSet:{code:"$materialCode",class:"$materialClass"}},
      }
    },
    {
      $sort:{"_id.date": 1}
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id:{date:"$_id.date"},
        locations: {$addToSet:  {location:"$_id.location",materials:"$materials"}},
      }
    },
    {
      $project:{_id:0, date:"$_id.date",locations:1}
    }
]).pretty()
```

Result of query returns

```
{
    "locations" : [
        {
            "location" : "123",
            "materials" : [
                {
                    "code" : "MATCODE",
                    "class" : "Class"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "location" : "1",
            "materials" : [
                {
                    "code" : "WTHFA",
                    "class" : "OtherClass"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "location" : "12345",
            "materials" : [
                {
                    "code" : "WTHFA",
                    "class" : "thirdClassOfMat"
                },
                {
                    "code" : "WTHFC",
                    "class" : "thirdClassOfMatter"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "date" : {
        "week" : 48,
        "month" : 11,
        "day" : 30,
        "year" : 2015
    }
}
```

Comment: Very close to what I need and way closer to what I was trying. Thanks!